# Send a push notification with Firebase Console when andorid app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can send push notification from Firebase Console to Android App when it'is in background or foreground. But If app is Killed push is not delivered.

I set "priority high" to custom data in Additional Options of Compose Notification:

[image: cloud messaging set]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: same issue bro let alone us even for "Instagram" if killed it does not work although the documentation says so i think what the documentation means to say is if application was closed by the user not when the user "force stop" the application

Comment: @AdityaBhawsar It's not true for facebbok/instagram: If I force stop push is delivered anyway